# Empty folder generated when saving video Android App

Tags: java, android, kotlin, mobile, mobile-application

[Gallery](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1iNRD.jpg)

I save the downloaded video in the Internal Storage of the application to the External Storage and put it inside the Movies folder (Movies/FacebookDownload). My code works fine but it also creates an empty folder included, how to delete it. My English is a bit bad, sorry

This is the code that saves the video to my external storage

```
fun saveVideo(context: Context, filePath: String?, fileName: String?) {
        filePath?.let {
            val values = ContentValues().apply {
                val folderName = "${Environment.DIRECTORY_MOVIES}/FacebookDownload"
                put(MediaStore.Video.Media.DISPLAY_NAME, fileName)
                put(MediaStore.Video.Media.TITLE, fileName)
                put(MediaStore.Video.Media.MIME_TYPE, "video/mp4")
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 29) {
                    put(MediaStore.Video.Media.RELATIVE_PATH, folderName)
                    put(MediaStore.Video.Media.DATE_ADDED, System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000)
                    put(MediaStore.Video.Media.IS_PENDING, 1)
                } else {
                    put(MediaStore.Video.Media.DATE_ADDED, System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000)
                }
            }
            val fileUri = if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
                val collection = MediaStore.Video.Media.getContentUri(MediaStore.VOLUME_EXTERNAL_PRIMARY)
                context.contentResolver.insert(collection, values)
            } else {
                context.contentResolver.insert(MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values)!!
            }
            if (fileUri != null) {
                context.contentResolver.openFileDescriptor(fileUri, "w", null).use { descriptor ->
                    descriptor?.let {
                        try {
                            FileOutputStream(descriptor.fileDescriptor).use { out ->
                                val videoFile = File(filePath)
                                FileInputStream(videoFile).use { inputStream ->
                                    val buf = ByteArray(8192)
                                    while (true) {
                                        val sz = inputStream.read(buf)
                                        if (sz <= 0) break
                                        out.write(buf, 0, sz)
                                    }
                                    out.flush()
                                    out.close()
                                }
                            }
                        } catch (e: Exception) {
                            return
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            values.clear()
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
                values.put(MediaStore.Video.Media.IS_PENDING, 0)
            }
            try {
                if (fileUri != null) {
                    context.contentResolver.update(fileUri, values, null, null)
                }
            } catch (_: Exception) {
            }
            File(it).delete()
        }
    }
```

Please tell me where my code is failing, and how to delete the empty folder "Movies"